# Could anyone please explain the meaning of this theme song (Le petit Nicolas)

Tags: paroles-de-chanson

I am trying to learn French and I came across this cartoon called Le Petit Nicolas. It has a catchy theme song, which I cannot understand. I mean I can literally translate it, but I believe that there are some phrases used in this song that have an altogether different meaning.

```
Chouette! Me voilà! 
Tous à l'enfance! 
Le p'tit Nicolas 
Quitte la classe 

Je suis l'enfant 
De vos enfances 
Ou bien l'enfance 
De vos mémoires 
Poussière de craie 
Et carte de France 
Boules de papier 
Sur tableau noir
```

Comment: What don't you understand ? At first sight, the first 2 sentences may be tricky, the other ones seems to be natural.

Comment: Does the first line mean "Owl, I am here!" That sounds very awkward...

Comment: Indeed, it does not mean "owl" ;) Is it the only sentence you don't understand ? You have to be clear so one can make an answer including every point you need...

Comment: Chouette means Cool in colloquial French. Or Nice.

Comment: This question is too vague and to attract a good answer. Please visit [help centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help) to see what kind of questions are expected here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool! Here I am! 
Let's go to childhood
The little Nicolas 
Leaves school 

I am the kid 
From your childhoods 
Or maybe the childhood 
Of your memories 
Chalk dust 
And map of France 
Paper balls 
On blackboard 
 
Yep, makes only a little more sense in English than in French (I speak fluently) 
The second line suggests that he is about to leave school (at least for the holidays) to go enjoy 'childhood'.
The second stanza sort of lists typical childhood objects in the classroom (at least at the time of writing).
Hope this helps, please comment if there is anything else you don't understand and I will answer.

Comment: FL is not a translation service and questions & answers are not expected to be translations but about language.

Comment: Oops sorry my bad (new user)

Comment: No need to apologize. Question was not worded properly anyway. Welcome to FL and do come back.